Land reclamation on a world with extreme tides
My narrative project is set on a gas giant's habitable moon. As there are multiple moons orbiting the gas giant I have recently calculated how powerful the tides on the habitable moon would be. The result was that the average tidal range caused by the closest moon would be of 30 to 40 meters in the middle of the ocean. The other tides would be below the 10 meters range and thus be manageable everything considered.
Which according to floodmap would lead to shoreline changes visisble from space.
Now the easiest way to solve this problem would be to decrease the mass of the other moons or even better increase the distances between them. But beforehand I'd like to examine the opportunity of having the civilization(s) that arose on the moon develop advanced methods of land reclamation to cope with their environment.
Such as by building progressively tall seawalls the closer they got to the coasts in a way similar to what the Dutch did in the Netherlands. Not to mention developing means of harnessing the power of the tides as a source of energy.
Do you think it would make sense for them to go down this route? Or is this tidal range just too overwhelming for the civilizations to ever attempt at settling the coasts or engage in sea-faring?
Also here is the image that inspired the idea:

Its the Vekta wall of killzone
For some additional context
The moons, including the one that is habitable, are all tidally locked to the gas giant and the eccentricity is negligible, therefore the gas giant itself wouldn't cause relevant tides. As each moon would be locked to the other in a 2:3 resonances such extreme scenarios would happen only once every 2 days but they'd still happen nonetheless. Also there would be rather frequent earthquakes due to the tidal interaction. The gas giant also is tilted by 30 degrees along it's axis of rotation and thus the satellites have 30 percent orbital inclination relative to the gas giant's orbital plane, that ensures that for most of the year the gas giant doesn't cause total eclipses on the side that faces it.

It is not clear what is the intended meaning of the phrase "average tidal range". If this means that the tidal range somewhere in the middle of the ocean is 30 to 40 meters, then that's bad. Really bad, because that would be about 40 times as much as here on Earth, and the tidal range on the shores of the oceans would be something to behold from a safe distance.

@AlexP according to the calculator I have got from Artifexian, that's 30 to 40 meters in the middle of the ocean yes, i'll clarify

I see how piles are put in on the wet side of a tidal range on Earth, how on EarthX would a civilisation build what's in the picture whilst being battered by high tide a couple of times a day? Does that seem practical to you?

Since you state the moon is also tidally locked to it's primary you also have a second major problem to deal with on top of the giant tides i.e constant near gale force wind speeds. This is a result of one side of the moon facing 'sun wards' & one being in constant darkness (the night side) albeit light reflected off the primary might provide illumination to the night side.   But even if it does the difference in temperature between the two sides is going to create gale force winds as heat from the day side travels to the dark side and cold air from the dark side travels the reverse direction.

@Escapeddentalpatient.  They'd not start with these super dams, they'd start inland and built progressively bigger dams as their construction techniques and technology progressed.

@Mon They are tidally locked to the gas giant, not the star. They rotate around the gas giant.

@JuimyTheHyena.  Yes of course, but visualize the orbit. The moon rotates around the primary with one side ALWAYS facing it. No matter how you work it out the side facing towards the gas giant is never going to get as much sunlight as the side facing away. Some yes but never as much as the other side.

@Mon oh dear..I forgot to mention that the that the gas giant axis of rotation is tilted and so are the orbits of the satellites. I'll rectify now.

@JuimyTheHyena. As you wish. The thing is I'm just not sure that solution actually solves the problem. If it does? All well and good. If it doesn't? As I see it? Changing the primary's axis of rotation doesn't really solve the problem. The issue being I can't conceive of a mathematical solution to orbital mechanics that gives you the outcome it wants

@Mon hmmm changing the axis of the primary changes also the inclination of the orbits, which ensures that the primary cannot eclipse the sun for most of the year, see my point?

Inland or partly enclosed bodies of water
Part of why tides are so high is because there's a huge volume of water available to move; as you probably know, your average pond or river doesn't experience any tides. For that same reason, a lot of inland seas (i.e. the baltic) don't experience the same tidal variation as most other oceanic coast. Basically you want something where there's not very much water easily available to throw around, or at least that the water has somewhere else to go.
Unfortunately, I don't know that land reclamation would be very easy with forces like that. Maybe consider some kind of coral analogue?
To be fair, you're still probably going to be able to have ports - it's just that most will be inland on rivers, or on those smaller seas and lakes. Lots of places already have ports on their rivers, though, so you'd totally be able to have seafarers. The seas would probably be more treacherous, though, you might have goofy moments where ships get stranded miles inland... which, to be fair, is another potential option. If you're okay with having a ship that stays beached a few feet above sea level most of the time, you could probably wait on a tidal flat with it and have the tides come in, ride those, and avoid whatever churny coastal erosion maelstrom might be at the actual shore.
You'll also probably have big brackish environments and funky tide poolish environs! Could be fun. Imagine tidally flooded rice field analogues and flat boats with which farmers navigate them during the flooded times - perhaps poles to tie them to. Anyways, tides are a fun idea to work with. Location becomes much more dynamic, anyways, over time this way.
(fyi this is all totally speculative, I'm not an expert)

Hmm question what do you mean with coral analogue?

Well - coral in general can sort of build up reefs. I imagine a terrain that has the ability to regenerate itself and grow would be a useful element of any world with an otherwise high rate of tidal erosion. But thinking about it now, any biological element could work, depending; mangroves are already used to combat coastal erosion after all. You could also get more fanciful and have something like a floating island. I've been to lakes before that had reeds & grasses supporting a little bit of soil right at the lake surface. It was weird... basically, nature seeks equilibrium - great excuse!

I was also thinking about this a bit and realized that you might actually have good excuses for these really large scale engineering projects to occur, where a safe area maybe on a river turns into a huge metropolis over time, but the coast washes away too so that by the time the coast threatens the city, they actually have the tech to protect it, plus the people to make it worthwhile

And, to be fair, you could also have places where the coast is at relative equilibrium and the tides deposit as much as they take away - probably somewhere with low, broad coastal plains and shallow water for a good ways, or near a river where sediment is being actively supplied. I imagine the tides like flattening things out, so somewhere that's already very flat wouldn't actually have much of a problem.

Hmm excellent suggestion, I think it's enough to close the matter

Happy to be of help!

Think of estuaries, such as the River Severn in the UK. That has 15m tides and ports such as Bristol. People settle and build ports just beyond the highest tide. They will probably do the same on your planet. There will be long mudflats and long jetties to get to the boats at neap and spring tide.
I am writing this from Grange-over-Sands on Morecombe bay. Here's some pictures and info on the local jetties.
Seaside with cliffs would probably be bad places to live with tides like that. Hard to get at the sea where the fish are. Strong erosion. However, the Faroe Islands have huge granite cliffs, but the people still manage to find places for normal looking ports.
Good picture, though.

We get 15 meter tides in some places, on a planet where the mid-ocean tidal range is 1 meter. On a planet where the mid-ocean tidal range is 40 meters, ...

@AlexP pheraps the extreme tidal changes in the middle of the ocean would lead to less costal features that would amplify the tides that much? Hmmm should I make it it's own question?

@JuimyTheHyena: To get an idea, go to Flood Maps (or any other such site), set the sea level 40 meters above current and see what would happen here on Earth. The Netherlands, Bangladesh and most of Florida are gone, Denmark and Crimea are islands, the Caspian connects to the Black Sea (and through the Black Sea to the ocean) etc.

@AlexP Flood maps was the exact site I used to verify the effects, I have mentioned it in the question, second paragraph. I am well aware of how devastating these tides would be, what you made me come to mind is wether or not this planet would have costal features similar to earth that would further amplify or pheraps diminish the tides.

Caissons are pretty much your only option for building any infrastructure in the intertidal zone on a world that experiences tides on this scale, and they'd need to be huge. But you don't need to build there to have coastal settlements and a seafaring civilisation. What you need are strands, shallow [gradient] beaches, or mudflats, near the high tide shoreline where your boats can be high and dry during low tide, allowing them to be loaded and unloaded. This does require building shallow draft vessels that can be beached without breaking their keels but this was very common throughout human history, in fact it's how things were generally done for millennia, the regular use of deep water habours is actually a relatively new thing. The first harbours on the Thames (London), Severn (Gloucester), Tamar (Plymouth) and Test (Southhampton) were all mudflat strands on the north coast of France, Calais, and Dunkirk started as beach strands, and many modern fishing villages all over the world still use beach strands for their boats when not at sea.
